# Angular service with a dependency that has a default value - build error unknown identifier []

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-cli

I created a service like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TestService {
  value: any;
  constructor(value: string = 'a') {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

It fails to build with `ng build -aot`

```
ERROR in : Error: Internal error: unknown identifier []
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24170:27)
    at C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18100:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at InjectableCompiler.depsArray (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18066:25)
    at InjectableCompiler.factoryFor (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18130:36)
    at InjectableCompiler.injectableDef (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18149:44)
    at InjectableCompiler.compile (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18159:106)
    at C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24015:90
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler._emitPartialModule2 (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24015:25)
    at C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24008:48
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler.emitAllPartialModules2 (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24007:26)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._emitRender2 (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:300:31)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.emit (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:201:22)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._emit (C:\MyProject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:879:49)
```

And a warning before that:

> Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for TestService in C:/MyProject/src/app/shared/context/test.service.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x

A strange thing about this warning is that in fact I'm using **Angular 7.2** while the error warns me that this will be an issue in Angular 6...

---

I found a way around it, changing the service to use a factory function:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root', useFactory: () => new TestService('a') })
export class TestService {
  value: any;
  constructor(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Now it builds successfully but the warning message remains. And I'm not sure this is the right way to solve it.

How should I create a service that has a dependency and provide a default value for it?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround from the original question is fine and the warning messages are a bug from the Angular compiler. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34925#event-2975512691

Nevertheless it might be better to use a DI token. Something like this:

```
export const TEST_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('mytoken', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => 'default value',
})

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TestService {
  value: any;
  constructor(@Inject(TEST_TOKEN) value: string) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

This way there is a default value which can be changed using Angular's DI providers: `{provide: TEST_TOKEN, useValue: 'some other value'}`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Services should not hold any parameters.
If you choose to construct it that way you can't use it in a DI scenario and it will cause you problems down the line.
My advice is to use a public method setValue(). and create the variable with default value.